# Exploring neighboring nodes on a graph

Tags: network-programming, netlogo

I am working on a project in netLogo in which i have a random network in which each and every link is assigned a bandwidth. The algorithm chooses a random Source and Destination by itself and after which it has to choose an optimal path between these two.
My question is how shall i ask turtles whicj i created on a particular code to face and move on its neighbour nodes so as to explore the graph(atleast explore ,if it doesnt manage to reach the destination )
few trtles must travel on nodes other than "relay nod" also (the relay node is the optimal node path, but i want nodes to explore other nodes aswell).
heres my code part:

```
 to face-targets
 ask ants ;with [ target-node]; = node 4 ]    ;nobody ]
 [

 let d 0

 face (one-of nodes with [ label = "Relay Node" ]);target-node
  ask current-node [
    set d distance  (one-of nodes with [ label = "Relay Node" ]);target-node)

  ] 
  set distance-to-go d

  ]
  end

  to move-forward
  face-targets 

  ask ants [
   while [  distance-gone < (distance-to-go  )]
  [


   fd  1
   set distance-gone (distance-gone + 1)
   ]
  ]
    ask ants [
       if distance-gone < distance-to-go

       [
        set current-node target-node 
        setxy ([xcor] of current-node) ([ycor] of current-node)
        set distance-gone 0
        set distance-to-go 0

        ]
       ]
        end
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear what you're asking. In general, you should try to narrow your questions down to a specific problem you need help with.

That said, my general approach to what you describe would look something like this:

```
turtles-own [ current-node ]

to go
  ask ants [
    let next-node pick-next-node
    face next-node ;; This is purely for visual reasons and is not necessary to the behavior of the model
    move-to next-node
    set current-node next-node
  ]
end

to-report pick-next-node
  ;; Whatever strategy you want your ants to use to pick their next node. For example, random:
  report one-of [ link-neighbors ] of current-node
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think no one has answered this yet because:

- The code is chaotically indented and has lots of commented-out stuff in it, so it's hard to read
- It's unclear what your actual question is. What is it about the code you've written so far isn't meeting your goals...?

If you fix those two things (S.O. questions are editable), you'll have a lot better chance of getting useful feedback from someone here.

There are two relevant Code Examples in NetLogo's Models Library I suggest you look at:

- Link-Walking Turtles Example
- Move Towards Target Example

In the former, the turtles move to the next node all at once; in the latter, they proceed gradually. I'm not sure which it is you're trying for? Normally if you're doing network stuff you would do the former approach; from your code, it appears you're trying for the latter, but it isn't clear why.

Note that you can replace `setxy ([xcor] of current-node) ([ycor] of current-node)` with just `move-to current-node`.